# Home page problem (maybe css related)

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, helix3, class-extensions

I have just made a new installation of Joomla from scratch and adopted the Helix Ultimate, but the look of the home page is quite different.

My site: http://www.casalpinachezal.it/
Demo Helix: http://demo.joomshaper.com/?template=helixultimate

It seems that part of the css/class are not loaded properly.

Do you have ideas on where is the problem?

Thanks.

Riccardo

Comment: Please try to describe your issue in words in your question body so that search engines can effectively index this page.  Are you able to narrow down the elements or attributes that are being affected?  A question that plonks down a weblink, points at it and says, "it's not right" -- doesn't make a high quality post here and it isn't very attractive to answer.  Please try to improve your question details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but your website has some duplicated CSS IDs e.g.:

```
id="sppb-addon-1.51206879815E+12"

id="section-id-1.51927852025E+12"
```

CSS ID selectors should be unique.

[Also, CSS selectors should only have hyphens, underscores, letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000).

You may need to update the CSS IDs in the page builder and make the corresponding changes in the custom CSS.